# Seminorms of $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ using smooth vector fields

Tags: vector-fields

The space $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is a Fréchet space with seminorms
$$
\max_{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^d, |\alpha| \leq k} \sup_{x \in K} |D^{\alpha}f(x)|
$$
where $K$ is compact and $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
Here I use, for any $\alpha = (a_1,\ldots,a_d)$, the notation $|\alpha| = a_1 + \ldots + a_d$ and more importantly:
$$
D^{\alpha}f = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\right)^{a_1} \cdots \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_d}\right)^{a_d} f
$$

**I am wondering if instead of using $\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$, one could use any family of smooth vector fields spanning the tangent space at any point.**
For example when $d=2$:
$$
(1+y^2)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \qquad \frac{\partial}{\partial y}
$$
In particular, I am interested in how these seminorms are related to the usual ones and what happens when the operators do not commute.
Also, is the assumption that they span the tangent space *at any point* needed?
Here is an example when the family is always a basis, except at the origin:
$$
y\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \qquad \frac{\partial}{\partial y}
$$